# cockroachdb: print only tuples

Tags: sql, cockroachdb

is there any output option for `cockroach sql` command to print only tuples without column names and rows count?

`psql` has `-t, --tuples-only        print rows only` flag.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the `cockroach sql` CLI has a way to hide column names or row counts. It does accept a `--format` argument that lets you change the output format into CSV or other formats.

You can also connect to CockroachDB using `psql` and it will work fine.

Comment: i haven't find convenient way to export database scheme to CSV file and then import